# how to print a list with the line number in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to format a list in Scheme and print out formatted list with a line number before each result.

Given the list :

```
(define tree '
  ("S"
   ;;;inside S node
   (
    ("-" ("A" 3333) ("A" 4444))
    ;;;inside W node
    ("W"
     (
      ("+" ("R" 0) ("R" 1))
      ("+" ("R" 1) ("R" 2))
      ("+" ("R" 2) ("R" 3))
      ("+" ("R" 3) ("R" 4))
      ("+" ("R" 4) ("R" 5)));;;end of adds
     (("-" ("R" 0) ("R" 1))
      ("-" ("R" 1) ("R" 2))
      ("-" ("R" 2) ("R" 3))
      ("-" ("R" 3) ("R" 4))
      ("-" ("A" 1000) ("A" 2000)));;;end of subs
     );;;end of W node
    );;;end of S node
  )
)
```

(It is a big "S" list with 2 sub lists "-" and "W" inside).
And here is my code:

```
(define (visit a)
  (bigDumpNode a)
  )
;;;open the big S list
(define (bigDumpNode a)
  (cond
    ((eq? (car a) "S")
     (bigSDumpList (cadr a))
     )
  )
)
;;;Loop the inner list
;;;There will be  "-" list and "W" list
(define (bigSDumpList a)
  (for-each (lambda (x)
              (intoSmall x)
  )a)
)


(define (intoSmall a)
  ;;;inside W list, we do have more smaller lists
  (cond
    ((eq? (car a) "W")
     (dumpWhile (cdr a))
     )
    ((or
      (eq? (car a) "+")
      (eq? (car a) "-")
      (eq? (car a) "*")
      (eq? (car a) "/"))
         (dumpTwoOperand a)
      )
  )
 )


(define (dumpWhile a)
  (dumpWhileLoop a)
  )
;;;loop through the inner W list
(define (dumpWhileLoop a)
  (for-each (lambda (x)
              (operandLoop x)
              (display "\nbne $00000000")
              )a)
  )

(define (operandLoop a)
  (for-each (lambda (x)
              (dumpTwoOperand x)
              )a)
  )
;;;format the + - * / and print add sub mul div console
(define (dumpTwoOperand a)
  (cond
    ((eq? (car a) "+")
     (display "\nadd")
     (twoOP(cdr a))
     )
    ((eq? (car a) "-")
     (display "\nsub")
     (twoOP(cdr a))
     )
    ((eq? (car a) "*")
     (display "\nmul")
     (twoOP(cdr a))
     )
    ((eq? (car a) "/")
     (display "\ndiv")
     (twoOP(cdr a))
     )
    )
  )
;;;format A to $ and R is still R
(define (twoOP a)
  (oprand1 a)
  (oprand2 a)
  )

(define (oprand1 a)
  (cond
    ((eq? (caar a) "A")
     (display " $")
     (display (cadar a))
     )
    ((eq? (caar a) "R")
     (display " R")
     (display (cadar a))
     )
    )
  )

(define (oprand2 a)
  (cond
    ((eq? (caadr a) "A")
     (display " $")
     (display (cadadr a))
     )
    ((eq? (caadr a) "R")
     (display " R")
     (display (cadadr a))
     )
    )
  )
```

When I type (visit tree) in the console, it will output below:

```
sub $3333 $4444
add R0 R1
add R1 R2
add R2 R3
add R3 R4
add R4 R5
bne $00000000
sub R0 R1
sub R1 R2
sub R2 R3
sub R3 R4
sub $1000 $2000
bne $00000000
```

What I want is to add line number before each output, for example:

```
0: sub $3333,$4444
1: add R0,R1
2: add R1,R2
3: add R2,R3
4: add R3,R4
5: add R4,R5
6: bne $00000000
...
```

How can I do this?
Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to write the formatting code to return strings, one for each line of the output, instead of directly printing to the console. Then you can pass the resulting list of strings to a function that concatenates them while inserting line numbers and newlines. Finally, display that string to the console.

(Note: Out of necessity I've refactored your code a bit. Also, I've used some Racket-specific constructs, e.g., `for/list`, so you may have to alter those parts for other Schemes.)

```
(define (visit a)
  (let* ([line*     (format-node a)]
         [formatted (format-line* line* 0)])
    (display formatted)))

(define (format-node a)
  (case (car a)
      [("S") (append* (map format-group a))]))

(define (format-group a)
  (case (car a)
    [("W")             (append* (map format-while (cdr a)))]
    [("+" "-" "*" "/") (list (format-two-operand a))]))

(define (format-while a)
  (let* ([formatted-op* (map format-two-operand a)])
    (append formatted-op* '("bne $00000000"))))

(define (format-two-operand a)
  (let* ([operator (car a)]
         [op-name (case operator
                    [("+") "add"]
                    [("-") "sub"]
                    [("*") "mul"]
                    [("/") "div"])]
         [operand1 (cadr a)]
         [operand2 (caddr a)])
    (format "~a ~a ~a" op-name (format-operand operand1) (format-operand operand2))))

(define (format-operand operand)
  (let* ([type   (car operand)]
         [value  (cadr operand)]
         [prefix (case type
                   [("A") "$"]
                   [("R") "R"])])
    (format "~a~a" prefix value)))

(define (format-line* line* initial-line#)
  (let ([formatted-line* (for/list ([line line*]
                                    [line# (in-naturals initial-line#)])
                           (format "~a:\t~a\n" line# line))])
    (string-append* formatted-line*)))
```

This gives me the following output for your sample data:

```
0:  sub $3333 $4444
1:  add R0 R1
2:  add R1 R2
3:  add R2 R3
4:  add R3 R4
5:  add R4 R5
6:  bne $00000000
7:  sub R0 R1
8:  sub R1 R2
9:  sub R2 R3
10: sub R3 R4
11: sub $1000 $2000
12: bne $00000000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That looks so sweet!!

Comment: @zuolizhu You're welcome! If you're satisfied with my answer, a good way to thank me is to mark it as accepted.